# What's the best way to structure the DOM?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

When I set the block style to ng-template my `class="icon d-none d-sm-block"` doesn't work.

How to fix it?

```
<div class="icon d-none d-sm-block" *ngIf="user; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
<ng-template #thenBlock>
    <fa-icon [icon]='["fas", "user-alt"]' class="text-primary mr-1"></fa-icon>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2 btn-sm auth-btn">Logout</button>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2 btn-sm auth-btn">Login</button>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the whole `div` gets repaced when the `then` and `else` conditions are used.

Maybe try something like this:

```
<div class="icon d-none d-sm-block">
 <ng-container *ngIf="user; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #thenBlock>
    <fa-icon [icon]='["fas", "user-alt"]' class="text-primary mr-1"></fa-icon>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2 btn-sm auth-btn">Logout</button>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-2 btn-sm auth-btn">Login</button>
</ng-template>
```

Then everything should get rendered correctly inside the `div`